# Regular expressions to match flight number

Tags: regex

Basically, I want to write a regex to match flight number with format `AA123` or `AA1234`.

```
\b[A-Z]{2}\d{3,4}\b
```

That is two letters plus 3 or 4 digits. My solution and results are shown in the picture. I cannot understand why it fails when omitting spaces between words.

- Results with spaces
  [image: Results with spaces]
- **[Results without spaces](https://www.debuggex.com/r/u-OEptnSYW82AuRH)** <sup>debuggex</sup>
  [image: Results without spaces]

Comment: Please add the sample text and pattern into the question itself.

Comment: Please add your code to your question here, leaving SO to see something relevant to the question should be optional and not necessary to aid you.

Comment: It *"fails"* because of the word boundary assertions in there (`\b`)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I've been idle for a long time here, but shouldn't that simply be an answer?

Comment: @Jonast92 maybe, but I'm not really sure what the OP is really asking for, so I won't answer until that's clear.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Fair enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Lucas mentions in the comment, the word boundaries `\b` account for the fact that your regex fails when there are no spaces around the flight codes.

Since you are using the pattern in Python, you can use lookarounds to restrict the enclosing context for the pattern. Say, the pattern should match if it is not preceded with an uppercase letter (as it should start with a capital letter) and should not be followed with a digit (as it should end with a digit).

**In your case** use

```
(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]{2}\d{3,4}(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qB1vB8/1)

The `(?<![A-Z])` negative lookbehind will fail a match if there is an uppercase letter before the two flight number uppercase letters, and the `(?!\d)` negative lookahead will fail the match if the 3 or 4 digits after two uppercase letters are followed with a digit.

**Other airline code regex considerations**

Since the airline codes may be more complex than this, and include letters, too, but not just 2 digits at the start, and after the first 2 chars there may be an optiona whitespace and the final digits may be from 2 to 4, consider using

```
(?<![\dA-Z])(?!\d{2})([A-Z\d]{2})\s?(\d{2,4})(?!\d)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qB1vB8/32).

**Details**

- `(?<![\dA-Z])` - no letter or digit right before the current location
- `(?!\d{2})` - no 2 digits allowed immediately to the right of the current location
- `[A-Z\d]{2}` - 2 digits or letters
- `\s?` - an optional whitespace
- `\d{2,4}` - two, three or four digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit immediately to the right of the current location is allowed.

Answer (score 6):

In fact, Airline codes may contain numbers. Ex: S7

Therefore the better regexp would be

`\b([A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]\d|\d[A-Z])\s?\d{3,4}\b`

if you really need finding flight numbers in strings without spaces. (Case sensitive)
First negative lookbehind and the last non-digits group serve as boundaries.

`(?<!([A-Z0-9]))(([A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]\d|\d[A-Z])\s?\d{3,4})(?:\D)`

Comment: You regexp worked the best. Only I had to use \d{2,4} because some tailnumbers have only two numbers at its end. By example: FR69.

Comment: @manuman94 However, it does not work in all cases, [example](https://regex101.com/r/v2umrE/1). See [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35688929/3832970).

Answer (score 2):

The flight can also consist of only 1 number like the [BA1](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/ba1) flight. Also the whitespace should be non-capturing:

```
^([A-Z]{3}|[A-Z\d]{2})(?:\s?)(\d{1,4})$
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a regex for you, but I did find this piece of information online which might be very useful for anyone reading this.

What we call a flight number is actually called a *flight designator*. This flight designator consists of three parts: `airline designator`, `flight number` and `operational suffix`.

These parts have the following format:

- Airline code: `XX(A)`
- Flight number: `0(0)(0)(0)`
- Operational suffix: `(A)`

Here `0` stands for any number, `A` for a letter and `X` for either of those. Everything in parentheses is optional.

So the format of a full flight designator would be: `XX(A)0(0)(0)(0)(A)` ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_codes))

A few things to keep in mind when trying to detect the flight number in a piece of text:

- The flight designator is not case sensitive.
- The flight designator can be
  preceded by either a white space, new line or nothing (start of
  string).
- The flight designator can be succeeded by either a white space,
  new line, nothing (end of string) or anything that's not a number or
  letter.
- The airline designator and flight number part are commonly separated by a white space.

Hope this helps!